# How to check if a view controller can perform a segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

This might be a very simple question but didn't yield any results when searching for it so here it is...

I am trying to work out a way to check if a certain view controller can perform a segue with identifier XYZ before calling the `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method.

Something along the lines of:

```
if ([self canPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueID"])
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueID"];
```

Possible?

Comment: Exactly the question i'm looking for the answer to at the moment...

Comment: Hey Dan I ended up using `@try @catch @finally`. It works fine.

Comment: I did as well, I just really hope there is actually a way of checking this.  As a rule, I try to avoid situations where an exception COULD be thrown during normal runtime situations.

Comment: Curious why you would not know in advance if a viewController could handle a segue. Is there a code design issue, etc.

Comment: @TOMATO In my case, I'd like this for an automatic configuration. If a thing has an associated segue, I can configure its UI to show that (specifically, it's `UITableViewCell` instances, and wanting to configure their accessory). There are plenty of other ways to achieve the same goal (I'm using one), but the ways I can think of lead to repetition, which I like to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

> Apps normally do not need to trigger segues directly.
> Instead, you configure an object in Interface Builder associated with
> the view controller, such as a control embedded in its view hierarchy,
> to trigger the segue. However, you can call this method to trigger a
> segue programmatically, perhaps in response to some action that cannot
> be specified in the storyboard resource file. For example, you might
> call it from a custom action handler used to process shake or
> accelerometer events.
>
> The view controller that receives this message must have been loaded
> from a storyboard. If the view controller does not have an associated
> storyboard, perhaps because you allocated and initialized it yourself,
> this method throws an exception.

That being said, when you trigger the `segue`, normally it's because it's assumed that the `UIViewController` will be able to respond to it with a specific `segue's` identifier. I also agree with Dan F, you should try to avoid situations where an exception could be thrown. As the reason for you not to be able to do something like this:

```
if ([self canPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueID"])
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueID"];
```

I am guessing that:

1. `respondsToSelector:` only checks if you are able to handle that message in runtime. In this case you can, because the class `UIViewController` is able to respond to `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. To actually check if a method is able to handle a message with certain parameters, I guess it would be impossible, because in order to determine if it's possible it has to actually run it and when doing that the `NSInvalidArgumentException` will rise.
2. To actually create what you suggested, it would be helpful to receive a list of segue's id that the `UIViewController` is associated with. From the `UIViewController` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I wasn't able to find anything that looks like that

As for now, I am guessing your best bet it's to keep going with the `@try` `@catch` `@finally`.

Answer (score 24):

To check whether the segue existed or not, I simply surrounded the call with a try-and-catch block. Please see the code example below:

```
@try {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:[dictionary valueForKey:@"segue"] sender:self];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Segue not found: %@", exception);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works great. Note that if you have an exception breakpoint, it will still break. You can however continue without crashing.

Comment: You may get memory leaks under ARC because it does not clean up after exception.

Comment: Do not use this. As Andy said it leaks the view controller sending the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` message, and all its child view controller (because UIKit retain the view controller but never gets the chance to release it due to the exception).

Answer (score 15):

```
- (BOOL)canPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSArray *segueTemplates = [self valueForKey:@"storyboardSegueTemplates"];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [segueTemplates filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier = %@", identifier]];
    return filteredArray.count>0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is good to know (though it is undocumented behaviour).

Comment: I regret that I only have one upvote to give.  Great use of predicates, Evgeny.

Comment: NB according to the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35060917/305913 , use of this  undocumented behaviour might cause your app to be rejected from the app store.

Comment: great, and btw you can also check for segueClassName if its a custom segue class.

Answer (score 15):

<sub>This post has been updated for Swift 4.</sub>

---

Here is a *more correct* Swift way to check if a segue exists:

```
extension UIViewController {
func canPerformSegue(withIdentifier id: String) -> Bool {
        guard let segues = self.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [NSObject] else { return false }
        return segues.first { $0.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String == id } != nil
    }

    /// Performs segue with passed identifier, if self can perform it.
    func performSegueIfPossible(id: String?, sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
        guard let id = id, canPerformSegue(withIdentifier: id) else { return }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: id, sender: sender)
    }
}

// 1
if canPerformSegue("test") {
    performSegueIfPossible(id: "test") // or with sender: , sender: ...)
}

// 2
performSegueIfPossible(id: "test") // or with sender: , sender: ...)
```

Comment: Great answer, I'm concerned about that  self.valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates"), "storyboardSegueTemplates" would be a private property as it's not exposed/documented anywhere.

Is this code passed through app store validation?

Anybody used this in your production applications?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the -(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method and do your logic there.

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"someSegue"]) {
        if (!canIPerformSegue) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Reference CanPerformSegue.swift](https://gist.github.com/anelad/6e4827a1f0b384e65bcec36caa143948)

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController{
    func canPerformSegue(identifier: String) -> Bool {
        guard let identifiers = value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [NSObject] else {
            return false
        }
        let canPerform = identifiers.contains { (object) -> Bool in
            if let id = object.value(forKey: "_identifier") as? String {
                return id == identifier
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
        return canPerform
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of Evgeny Mikhaylov's answer, which worked for me:

I reuse a controller for two views. This helps me reuse code.

```
if(canPerformSegueWithIdentifier("segueFoo")) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueFoo", sender: nil)
}
else {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueBar", sender: nil)
}


func canPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: NSString) -> Bool {
    let templates:NSArray = self.valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates") as! NSArray
    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier=%@", identifier)

    let filteredtemplates = templates.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    return (filteredtemplates.count>0)
}
```

Comment: I believe this method's name is reserved in iOS, as I'm experiencing unexpected behavior using this approach. It's better to rename it, e.g. to `canRunSegueWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 1):

It will be useful, before call performSegue, check native storyboard property on base UIViewController (for example screen was from StoryBoard or Manual Instance)

```
extension UIViewController {

func performSegueWithValidate(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) {
    if storyboard != nil {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
    }
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFBq.png)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to check that using the standard functions, what you can do is subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and store the information in the `source` view controller (which is passed to the constructor). In interface builder select "Custom" as the segue type as type the class name of your segue, then your constructor will be called for every segue instantiated and you can query the stored data if it exists.

You must also override the `perform` method to call `[source presentModalViewController:destination animated:YES]` or `[source pushViewController:destination animated:YES]` depending on what transition type you want.

Comment: Calling present, push and pop programmatically is very dangerous because the segue can be changed at any time from a model to a pushed scene. When you pop a modal it will crash. It is best to be sure that the named segue exists or use try/catch which I think is still pretty sloppy since it is not truly exceptional. There should be a method to check if a segue identifier is defined. This appears to be missing on purpose.