# Counting programmatically segues attached in Storyboard UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to count the segue attached in UIVIewController on the storyboard

Comment: You can count the segues in a `UITableViewController`, that's what you are saying? I wouldn't recommend it, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626469/how-to-check-if-a-view-controller-can-perform-a-segue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. There is no way to programmatically know how many segues are coming from a view controller without manually adding it yourself.

The `UITabViewController` does not actually have segues. Rather, it is assigned an array of ViewControllers that it owns and can easily count.